# React Redirect Browser from Background Timer

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app that starts a timer after login, that validates if the logged-in user's jwt authentication token needs to be refreshed.  It kicks in a minute before expiry of the token, and uses a cookie-based refresh token to request a jwt refresh from the server.  This process works without a problem.

My problem comes in when the token expires and the server does NOT return a new token.  At this point, I want the browser to redirect the user back to the login view of the react app so that they can login afresh.  But I am unsure of how to do this.

This timer is running in a UserService Module, that is not a react component, so I am unable to use the useHistory approach.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling that timer function inside `UserService` Module from a react component, passing a `callback function` to redirect would be a better solution.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  A callback function works brilliantly!